# Stuck at 640x480 resolution;

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, xubuntu, display-resolution

Okay so today I turn on my pc and my monitor is stuck at 640x480, I attempt to change the display settings but it wont let me change any of the options. I tried to switch to a different Nvidia driver (open source and proprietary) to no avail, tried switching back to the Nouveau driver too, still no luck. Not sure what caused this, but I think its happened due to something that updated, I remember when I was last on my pc letting it do some updates. How can I diagnose this and fix it?

Am on Xbuntu
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Comment: Edit... I just tried another proprietary driver (version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116) and it works fine. Testing switching back to open source now...

Comment: Just tried version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.09 (open source) (which I tried before :S) and it works, not sure what happened, but it must not have installed correctly. switching to the proprietary 390.116, and back seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

1. Search Nvidia packages

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
   ```
2. Remove all the Nvidia drivers

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
   ```
3. Go to: *Software Updates⇢Additional Drivers⇢select first one⇢Apply Changes⇢reboot*

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too!

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: I was having these issues after trying to install cuda toolkit and nVidia drivers. This helped, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like nomodeset.

Make sure that it isn't set somwhere in your ubuntu configuration

```
grep nomodeset /etc/ -rs
```

This should print by default only:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY nomodeset"
```

If it appears somwhere else, i.e. in `/etc/default/grub` - remove it and update grub configuration with

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Then reboot.

Also check which graphics driver is in use.

```
lspci -v
```

Look for your graphics card or VGA string sections.

In case it's

```
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

open applications menu and go to Updates -> Settings -> Additional Drivers

or via terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab 4
```

and install one of proprietary drivers available.

Keep in mind that after switching drivers you need to reboot your PC.

Comment: I had set `nomodeset` during installation, due to excessive screen tearing. But the installer worked at a higher resolution, so my initial thoughts were not to look for this item set in the actual installed grub conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this past week when I was reviving an older PC. No matter what Linux distro I installed, I was stuck at 640x480 resolution. I tried different video cards, proprietary BIOS settings,etc. I had an older version of OpenSUSE 12.3 (Dartmouth) installed on another partition and it worked fine with all resolutions. I tried installing a fresh version of OpenSUSE 12.3 and it also worked with all resolutions. All of the recent Linux distros I tried required me to use ACPI=off to boot. This avoided black screen, freezes, etc. but the resolution was stuck at 640x480

At this point, I decided it had something to do with the kernel, or drivers, or boot options. I tried every common kernel option list in this link,https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions, and found that using **nolapic** option was the solution. This worked with every distro that previously failed and all my resolutions work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I looked on different forum, without any success.
And I finally found I had a low latency kernel installed since my last update.
I checked before uninstalling it that I had another kerneil installed, which was ok, so I decided to uninstall this low latency kernel, and now everything is working fine.

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.
My current linux image version is 5.4.0-72.80, and I had a low latency kernel 5.8.0-x

Answer (score 0):

Tried answer from @Bhaskar S but that doesn't work for me. I tried to go to GRUB menu and pick a different kernel option and the full resolution is then back.